# Python: Parsing out publication dates from html pages

Tags: python, regex

For html pages, and news-related pages especially, it would be very helpful and incredibly useful if there were a mechanism for parsing out the publication dates.

Unfortunately, there is not one set regex/pattern for dates on the internet. CNN may publish it like MONTH DD, YYYY and HuffingtonPost may publish as MM/DD/YY, and so on.

Does anyone have any strategies which are better than just pure regex parsing for extracting publication dates out of html pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [parse](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) function from [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) library.

It uses some set of heuristics to detect date format. It works automagically :)

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse

>>> parse('April 12, 2013')
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 12, 0, 0)

>>> parse('04/12/13')
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 12, 0, 0)
```

There is one more good little date/time library for python — [times](https://github.com/nvie/times/). It uses dateutil inside as well, but it also helps to work properly with timezones.

```
>>> import times

>>> times.to_universal('2012-02-03 11:59:03', 'Europe/Amsterdam')
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 3, 10, 59, 3)

>>> times.to_local(_, 'Europe/Amsterdam')
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 3, 11, 59, 3, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

But for just detecting a date format regex is a good solution I think.

In a real project I would do the following steps:

1. Try to check date through a set of regexes (known date formats).
2. If it is in a known format — use stdlib [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) with a predefined pattern.
3. If it is in an unknown format — use slow parse from dateutil and write some warning to log.

Comment: Im reading through their api right now, looks interesting! But i'm having trouble finding the use you just described here http://labix.org/python-dateutil. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I just added a couple of examples above.

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually solves 1/2 my problem! The first half was actually detecting where the 'April 12, 2013' or '04/12/13' are present in the html files. But nice job regardless. If nobody responds after a day ill mark you as green

Comment: I added some thoughts about just format detection. Yes, I think regex is OK here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why a collection of regexs wouldn't work. There are a variety of different formats, but there are really only a handful that are most common. With, say, a dozen easy regex, you could probably scrub 90% of the dates out there.

Another (partial) approach would be to scan for month names and abbreviations, and then scan the surrounding text for days and year.

For numeric-only, the hardest part would be figuring out whether it's month then date or date then month. So will be easy, if the date part is greater than 12, but otherwise there's not really anyway of knowing.

You could also look for `<time>` elements with the `datetime` attribute, which is supposed to follow an unambiguous format (though not necessarily consistent).

Bottom line, I don't think there is any one way to find all the dates in a document, unless you know they all follow the same format, which obviously isn't going to be the case in general. To have a good shot of finding them, you'll just need to employ several different strategies.